# change cell color in ClosedXML while exporting sql data to excel

Tags: c#, closedxml

I need to change the color of a particular cell based on some conditions. I am already exporting whole table from MySQL to Excel, after exporting to Excel I want to change cell color in Excel file.
I am using ClosedXML library in C#.NET for exporting to Excel.

```
       private void ExportDataSetToExcel(DataSet ds)
        {
            string[] paths = { Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\"), "ExcelFiles" };
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(paths);
            string file = fullPath + "\\DataFile.xlsx";

            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {

                wb.Worksheets.Add(ds.Tables[0]);
                wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                wb.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGreen);
                wb.SaveAs(file);

            }


        }
```

Comment: you mean you are successful in exporting to excel and you need to do some formating on excel ?

Comment: what  have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I am able to export sql table to excel now I have to do formatting on excel cell

Comment: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Style-Rows-and-Columns

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
ws.Row(6).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Blue
ws.Column("E").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Blue;
```